# How to get 1 day started from today specific timestamp plus 24 hours

Tags: php, datetime, date-math

Currently I've used this code to get 1 day started from current timing of today plus 24 hours:

```
$daysago = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(date('Y-m-j H:i:s')) + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60));  //Today + 1 day
```

How can I fixed the timestamp so for example the `$daysago` should start from 9am of today until 9am of tomorrow only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to use `DateTime()` since it is better for working with dates and times. Just create a DateTime object with a 9AM time (which defaults to today's date) and then add a day to it.

```
 $daysago = (new DateTime('09:00'))->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/239700)

You can also use `DateInterval()` to add one day:

```
 $daysago = (new DateTime('09:00'))->add(new DateInterval('P1D'))->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Sorry for your inconvenience. You can just ignore my previous comment, my concern now is how to make `DATETIME` follow my current country timestamp since it seems like the current `09:00` is not follow `09:00` in my country. How can I make `DATETIME` to follow my country timestamp?

Comment: I'm living in Singapore so it's UTC/GMT +8 hours

Comment: What timezone is the date stored in?

Comment: If the time is stored in the proper timezone you don't need to do anything. This will work as is.